# How to handle port traffic only to Docker Swarm nodes that have the service that exposes that port?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

If we imagine that the Docker Swarm consists of node A, B and C.
If we imagine that we run a Docker Stack of a single service (for the sake of example), scaled to 2 instances and that service exposes port 80 of the host machine.

How do I make sure that any traffic that hits:

```
http://A:80
http://B:80
http://C:80
```

Always lands on a live Docker instance.

Given that there are 2 instances of the service and 3 nodes total, there will always be at least one node that doesn't have the service on it, so it will not expose port 80 (I assume).

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of using orchestration with e.g. swarm mode is that **you must not now anything about single nodes** in your swarm. Instead swarm works on a higher level of abstraction than nodes --> on `services`.

So you tell swarm which nodes it consists of, what services you have and how many instances of containers you want to run inside the swarm for each single service. After configuring that it is swarm's job to decide/know which container runs on which node. Again: you don't care about the single nodes.

So the question is not how to make

```
http://A:80
http://B:80
http://C:80
```

(Re)route to a correct/valid node (running a corresponding container with exposed port)

because the only thing you need to know is the name of your service. So you only will call

```
http://myservice:80
```

And then swarm mode will decide on which node the request will be forwarded to (`http://A:80` or `http://B:80` or `http://C:80`). And if you have 3 nodes, 1 service and 2 replicas for that service swarm will ensure that no requests will be forwarded to the node, on which no container is running because it knows there are only 2 replicas and it knows on which nodes these instances run.

Comment: Does this mean that if I make an HTTP request to ANY of the host machines (A, B or C) at port 80, those host machines will forward the request to `http://myservice:80` regardless of the fact that the service has no instances on that specific host (but other hosts within the Swarm have instances of it)?

Comment: The thing is: You don't make a HTTP request to any of the *host machines* (again, an advantage of using container orchestration like swarm is that you don't have to know anything about your cluster...neither how many hosts you have, nor their IP addresses). You make a request to the swarm service. And swarm will decide to which host the request will be forwarded to because it knows which containers are running on which hosts. This forwarding mechanism only works when using the defined swarm services.

Comment: Okay, but these "service names" are only defined within the same network where the Swarm was launched. To an outsider (e.g. a request that I make from the internet to the Swarm service) - I still need to point the request somewhere, e.g. an LB that forwards requests to the host machines in a round-robin fashion.

Comment: Exactly. This is when a reverse proxy like Traefik comes into play. You can solve this by letting traefik run on every master node in your swarm and then let the LB forward the request to one of the master nodes (in e.g. a round-robin fashion). Traefik will then handle the rest. I wrote some blog posts on that topic like https://codinghaus.de/2018/09/09/automated-load-balancer-haproxy-creation-on-digitalocean/ and especially https://codinghaus.de/2018/09/24/how-to-use-traefik-as-reverse-proxy-for-your-docker-swarm-mode-cluster-on-digitalocean-fully-automated-with-gitlab-ci-terraform-ansible/